# In Gradle, how can I filter an arbitrary string with no tokens?

Tags: gradle, filter, wsdl, cxf

Problem is that I have no control over the contents of the WSDL file. I cannot insert @@ or anything and yet I need to change some of the URI's so that the WSDL compiles. Basically, what I need to do is change 'someFileName.xsd' to '../../../some/file/path/someFileName.xsd'. I tried using ReplaceTokens but the tokens have to be Char for the setter methods. Note that I tried rewriting these with a catalog file earlier but I couldn't get that to work either. I forget what those errors were but it was enough to convince me to try something else. I am using CXF and 'no.nils:wsdl2java:0.8'.

Comment: You can write a `Copy` task and use `filter` along with closure to replace the line.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out eventually. Had to use regex replace filter.